# Strong vs weak entity types on SQL

Tags: mysql, database-design, mariadb, normalization, table

I have a 3NF normalized database design and was trying to understand the concept of strong vs weak entity types and my understanding is weak entity types are tables that don't have a primary key. However, surely all tables should have a primary key thus making them all a strong entity? So all my tables are strong entities? or am I missing something?

Rethinking, my junction tables have composite keys, (in maria db too make a composite you do PRIMARY KEY(column1, column2)) so would these class as weak entities?

Database design:
[image]

Comment: MySQL <> MariaDB.

Comment: You are expecting a "customer" to have multiple "accounts" and multiple "addresses"?  Don't use many-to-many tables when the relationship is not many-to-many.

Comment: @Rick James what? I’ve made a many to many table because it’s a many to many relation

Comment: Two customers share the same account?  Share the same address?

Comment: @Rick James yes there is something called a joint account? and people can live in the same address that usually how a house works...

Answer (score 5):

I've seen it mentioned in blogs and tutorials that a weak entity "doesn't have a primary key," but this is misleading.

You are correct that every table needs a primary key. This is necessary for the table to qualify as a relation. Every relation has one or more *candidate keys*, and one of the candidate keys is chosen as the table's primary key. The meaning of a candidate key is that the columns are non-NULL and they can be used to uniquely identify any row in the table.

The term weak entity is used for a table where the rows cannot exist without referencing some "parent" entity. For example, you might have tables `Users` and `Phones` such that a user can have zero, one, or multiple phones. But a phone number cannot exist without referencing its owning user.

Therefore `Users` is a strong entity; one row in the Users table can exist without regard to how many phones it has, or even if no phones reference it.

`Phones` is a weak entity. A given phone number cannot exist unless it references a row in `Users`.

A good way to implement this in SQL is to require that the primary key of the `Phones` table include a reference to the primary key of a row in `User`. But a user may own multiple phones, so there needs to be an additional column in `Phones` to make it a compound primary key. This is often called the *discriminator* and it's just an arbitrary value that serves to be distinct for each of the phones belonging to a given user. It doesn't necessarily have any other meaning, but sometimes people use it as an ordinal number for displaying the phones.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE Phones (
  owner_id INT NOT NULL,
  phone_ordinal INT NOT NULL,
  phone_number VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  phone_type VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (owner_id, phone_ordinal),
  FOREIGN KEY (owner_id) REFERENCES Users(user_id)
);
```

Some people state this as "Phones doesn't have a primary key" but they mean it doesn't have its own auto-incrementing integer column. It depends on values in the primary key of the `Users` table.

Many software developers confuse "primary key" with "an auto-incrementing integer column named `id`." This is a misunderstanding of what a primary key is. A primary key is a *constraint* applied to one or more columns, which together are a candidate key for the table. It does not necessarily mean the primary key is a single column, or that it is an integer, or that it is auto-incrementing.

---

P.S. I want to be clear that using auto-increment for a primary key is not the criterion for a strong entity. Auto-increment is not required by the relational model at all, it's just a convenience that is popular.